# Проблема при чтении списка загружаемых файлов

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть программа, которая создает список файлов такого формата

```
Config.dat CD875A24B64F1BDE6014D68E846365AD 1024
```

имя файла, хеш, размер
Но есть некоторые файлы, в названии которых есть пробел

```
BGM (25).30071 9755F66F2D04E3E05E51F4C8EE216E2D 42258
```

При скачивании получаю ошибку о неверном формате.  То есть строка делится не на три сигмента, как мне нужно, а на 4

```
public static UpdateFile FromString(string line)
    {
        if (line == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("line");

        if (line.StartsWith(" "))
            line = line.TrimStart();

        if (line.EndsWith(" "))
            line = line.TrimEnd();

        string[] segments = line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (segments == null || segments.Length != 3)
        {
            throw new FormatException("Переданная строка имеет неверный формат");
        }

        long fileSize = long.Parse(segments[2]);
        return new UpdateFile(segments[0], segments[1], fileSize);
    }
```

Подскажите, как я могу решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, можно распарсить вручную, формат-то простой.

```
//string s = "BGM (25).30071 9755F66F2D04E3E05E51F4C8EE216E2D 42258";
var i1 = line.LastIndexOf(' ');
var size = long.Parse(line.Substring(i1 + 1)); // 42258
var i2 = line.LastIndexOf(' ', i1 - 1);
var hash = line.Substring(i2 + 1, i1 - i2);   // 9755F66F2D04E3E05E51F4C8EE216E2D
var name = line.Substring(0, i2); // BGM (25).30071
```

Добавьте проверку ошибок по вкусу (`LastIndexOf` возвращает `-1`, если подстрока не найдена).

Далее можно конструировать `new UpdateFile(name, hash, size)`.

Comment: Подобных файлов у меня целая куча. Обновила вопрос, добавила свой метод, не поняла что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Елизавета: Ну замените `s` на `line`.

Comment: Запуталась совсем, не понимаю куда добавить строки в своем методе

Comment: @Елизавета: Ну выкиньте всё в вашем методе и замените на это. Что ж вам не только разжевать, но и в рот положить надо.

Comment: @Елизавета: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема может возникнуть только в начале(в названии), я бы сделал бы reverse, а потом Split, после этого, я бы взял 2 первых слова, а на остальном сделал бы join.

Как-то так:

```
      List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string str = "BGM (25).30071 9755F66F2D04E3E05E51F4C8EE216E2D 42258";
        string revStr = new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());
        var splitRevStr = revStr.Split();
        var hashAndSize = splitRevStr.Take(2).Select(x=>new string(x.Reverse().ToArray())).Reverse();
        var reverseName = splitRevStr.Skip(2).Select(x => new string(x.Reverse().ToArray()));
        var normalName = new string(string.Join(" ", reverseName).ToArray());
        result.Add(normalName);
        result.AddRange(hashAndSize);
```

Но я думаю, что код от @VladD будет побыстрее.

Ради интереса затестил. Мой код делается 2 млсек, а от @VladD за 0.

Answer (score 0):

A если так?

```
private List<string> f(string s)
{
    var l = new List<string>();
    var tmp = new StringBuilder();
    var size = s.Length;
    var counter = 0;

   for (int i = size - 1; i != 0; --i)
   {
       if (s[i] != ' ' && counter > 1)
       {
           tmp.Append(s[i]);
       }
       else
       {
           l.Insert(0, tmp.ToString());
           tmp.Clear();
           ++counter;
       }
   }

   return l;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.